# AMQP Inserting Message into Rabbit MQ

Tags: jmeter, rabbitmq, amqp

I am trying to insert message into Rabbit MQ with host, port, user, pass, exchange Queue, Queue Name and Routing Key

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEy5f.png)

getting these errors-
ForgivingExceptionHandler: An unexpected connection driver error occurred
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmRp1.png)

Can anyone suggest solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Please check permissions for user through which you are trying to connect to RabbitMq

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).